# Mobile Video in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, video.js, bootstrap-modal

I want a (bootstrap) modal dialog to contain a `<video>` tag (containing several mp4, webm and ogg sources). In desktop version/resolution, everything is fine. The modal is triggered/opened by an anchor tag and the video can be played inside.

**But now the problem/question: I want the video to be played "natively" from mobile devices (automatically enter fullscreen mode / open video app etc.) without opening the modal/lightbox.**

What do I have to do? I already tried to forward the click event to the `<video>`-Tag, but this doesn't help:

```
$('a.someclass').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var modal = $(this).siblings('.modal');
   var video = modal.find('video');

   // detect mobile devices
   if($('html').hasClass('small')) {
     // play video directly
     video.trigger('click');
   } else {
     // open modal for medium and large devices
     modal.modal('show');
   }    
});
```

The video receives the click event, but is just playing without triggering the mobile devices "native" events.

Should I trigger another event for mobile video playing? 
Could the modal's invisibililty be the problem?

Comment: You want that modal video to be displayed when page loads on Mobile?

Comment: If the lightbox opens up on Mobile, it's just way too small. Therefore i want the video to be played in fullscreen mode / natively on Mobile. For example: On my android I usually can choose an app to view a video.

Comment: `console.log($('html').hasClass('small'))` and check if this returns `true`?

Comment: Yes, `$('html').hasClass('small')` returns `true`.